# Trying to call navigator.accelerometer in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, accelerometer, navigator

Okay, so I am *learning* Phongap right now by going through examples. I have about 7-8 months of javascript exposure/experience, but I am completely new to xCode and Phonegap (about a week and a half maybe).  I don't feel that this effect my issue right now.

I don't want to out and ask, "Does navigator.accelerometer exist?", but that almost seems like the question right now.  I 'know' that is does exist, because its called everywhere in tons of examples, but when I actually try to call it, I get errors about it being undefined. I am doing this, but to no avail:

```
var foo = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

When I call `navigator.accelerometer` I get "'undefined' is not an object".

I have Phonegap installed and running when I compile, so I have no more ideas about what the problem could be.  I am assuming that this is not a deprecated property or syntax, and based on what I see in W3C schools, I have conclude (possibly ignorantly) that `accelerometer` is a property added to `navigator` by Phonegap.  Help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you add the required permissions? It's possible to forget them when trying out examples. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer_permissions

Comment: Will that need to be a separately added file? I don't see an App folder.  That should be generated on the phonegap create, right? Is that specific to Phonegap 2.0?

Comment: Check your config.xml for CDVAccelerometer plugin. (Or Cordova.plist if you use an old version of cordova).

Comment: Nothing like that in the config at all. No accelerometer or plugin

Comment: You need to add the plugin code, generally this means copying around some platform specific code, editing your config, and adding permission to use the new functionality. Here's the doc page for the latest version: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_add_features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your config.xml and add

```
<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
```

in the `<plugins>` section. Or, if you use cordova 3.0+

```
<feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

First bind `deviceready` event and call your method inside `onDeviceReady` function:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    // NOTE: implement onSuccess and onError callback functions
    var foo = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```